# Error changing alpha of PIL Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to set the alpha of an Image using the `PIL.Image` package along with `tkinter`. Here is my code.

```
background_image = Image.open(file_path + "\\static\\backgroundimage.jpg")
background_image = background_image.putalpha(128)
background_photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(background_image)
background_label = tkinter.Label(dashboard_page, image=background_photo)
background_label.background_image = background_photo
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

The error occurs on the second line. `background_image = background_image.putalpha(128)`. If I comment out this line the program works with no errors and displays the image. However if I uncomment this line I get this error. `AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'`. What is going on and how can I fix it? Thank you. I am using Python 3.4.4.

Comment: Do > `ImageTk.PhotoImage(background_image).putalpha(128)`

Comment: @DusanGligoric This throws an error: `AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'putalpha'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `.putalpha` changes the image directly and returns `None`, not a new image. Therefore, to fix the code, just replace

```
background_image = background_image.putalpha(128)
```

by

```
background_image.putalpha(128)
```

and it should work.